# Why there is no constraint on "Prover" in definition of $IP$?

Tags: complexity-theory, interactive-proof-systems

According to the definition of [$IP$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_%28complexity%29) given in Sanjeev Arora and Barak there is no constraint on the running time of the "Prover" ( when "verifier" sends a message to the "Prover" and expects a message in return from it ). Why is it so  ?
Also the book says the "Prover" might compute some undecidable function. How is that possible ? Am I missing something trivial ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing canonical for *what* constraint one might put on it. ​ Requiring complete efficiency would give BPP, since the algorithm can just simulate the whole interaction. ​ Requiring efficient-given-a-polynomial-length-string would give [MA](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:M#ma), since the prover could just send its string to the verifier. ​ It turns out that PSPACE is always enough, so letting the prover be at least that powerful yields the same class as not constraining the prover. ​ I suppose

things from [T](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:T#tfnp)F[UP](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:U#up) to [[CH](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:C#ch) given a polynomial-length string] might give intermediate classes.

Comment: If there are no constraints on the "prover" then can't we just take prover to be the oracle for the problem. Like this all languages belong to IP. What is the constraint I am missing ?

Comment: What would the verifier do? ​ (You're probably missing soundness.) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: So do you mean that the verifier must be able to verify in polynomial time, whatever the prover messages/aids it ?

Comment: No, although it must use the communication to assure itself that the instance is not a [NO instance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promise_problem#Formal_definition). ​ ​